# Construct a diffeomorphism $[a,b] \rightarrow [c,d]$ with slope 1 at $a$ and $b$

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds

I'm trying a problem from *An Introduction to Chaotic Dynamical Systems* regarding bump functions. At this point, we have successfully constructed, for any $\alpha < a < b < \beta$ a bump function $B \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ such that:

$B(x) \leq 0$ for $x \leq \alpha$ or $x \geq \beta$,

$B(x) = 1$ for $a \leq x \leq b$, and

$B'(x) \neq 0$ for all $\alpha < x < a$ and $b < x < \beta$.

The problem is to construct a $C^\infty$ diffeomorphism as in the title. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $g(x)$ I want is a sigmoid that goes from $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$, has zero derivative at both  ends and is $C^\infty$.  Probably you have shown that $f(x)= \begin {cases} 0&x \lt 0\\e^{-1/x} & x \ge 0 \end {cases}$ handles the end at zero just fine.  If so, some thought should convince you we can find $g(x)$.  Then the diffeomorphism is $h(x)=c+(x-a)+(d+a-c-b)g(\frac {x-a}{b-a})$

Comment: I can see why the function $h(x)$ you defined has $h(a) = c$, $h(b) = d$ and $h'(a) = h'(b) = 1$. But it's not yet clear to me that $h(x)$ is a diffeomorphism. The difficulty seems to be that $h'(x) = 1 - g'(\frac{x-a}{b-a}) + \frac{d-c}{b-a}g'(\frac{x-a}{b-a})$ may not have a fixed sign.